# Embedding of space in compact Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

James Munkres, in his book on Topology, mentions in introduction to separation axioms that the concept arises from study of some problem in topology than analysis, such as embedding of  a given (topological) space into compact Hausdorff space.

I am not expert in topology; can one explain a little, why one thinks of embedding of topological space into compact Hausdorff space? i.e., what is so importance about compact Hausdorff spaces? (I heard that, in Hausdorff spaces, limits of convergent sequences are unique).

Comment: A continuous injective map _from_ a compact space _to_ a Hausdorff space is always an embedding. Perhaps this is what is meant? (For example, an injective map from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R^2$ — an arc — is an embedding, but the map from $[0,2\pi)$ to $\Bbb R^2$ given by $\theta\mapsto(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ is not, and the map from $[0,1]$ with the usual topology to itself with the cofinite topology (check that this is continuous) is not.)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger I think Munkres is referring to the fact that a space is Tychonoff (completely regular, $T_{3\frac12}$, pick your favourite notation) iff it embeds into a compact Hausdorff space